# When i try to open settings in my odoo 12 localhost it gives me error (keyerror: "iap.account")

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I can't open settings when i click on it i got this error.

i tried to create new databases and i got the same error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed this error by downloading module called In-App Purchases from apps.